# Implement SAML2_Compat_AbstractContainer in SimpleSAMLphp low-level library

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

I want to use the SimpleSAMLphp low level SAML2 PHP library to generate a SAML request and send it to an IdP. For this I am trying to configure [SimpleSAMLphp low level library](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/saml2) . I have followed the steps mentioned in the usage guide. In the guide it mentions that I have to:

> Provide the required external dependencies by extending and implementing the `SAML2_Compat_AbstractContainer` then injecting it in the ContainerSingleton

I tried the code given in the example and it gives an error, stating that the `$container` object is null. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, you have to create a class extending `SAML2_Compat_AbstractContainer`, then instatiate this class into `$container` obejct and then pass it to `SAML2_Compat_ContainerSingleton::setContainer`. The example assumes that you did it already prior to `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` line.

```
class MyContainer extends SAML2_Compat_AbstractContainer {
    //...
}

$container = new MyContainer();

// Use Composers autoloading
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
//rest of the example
```